# R - how to make barplot plot zeros for missing values over the data range?

Tags: r, bar-chart

Lets say I have 10 observations of 200 points of integers between one and ten:

```
mysample = sample(rep(seq(1,10),20),10);
```

and I want to barplot it

```
barplot(table(mysample));
```

[barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lytzk.png)
[image]

In this example, there are no observations of 7. Is there a quick way of telling barplot to set the x-axis range to all integers between 1 and 10, or do I have to manually edit the table?

Comment: @DavidRobinson that sounds like a misuse of a histogram if you really want bars with counts. Histograms are for estimating an underlying probability density for continuous variables. This sounds like just counting observations of a discrete random variable.

Comment: @MrFlick is right, if I adjust the example such that the allowable values are not in equally spaced intervals then the quick and dirty histogram doesn't achieve the desired effect either.

Comment: is there a way how to add missing integer number without using table? my barplot is created as  barplot(df$area), I have an error when added as barplot(factor(df$area)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
barplot(table(factor(mysample, levels=1:10)));
```

[image]

By using a factor, R will know which levels are "missing"