# R: barplot {base} complete missing integer values on x axis

Tags: r

I have a barplot of counts per year. Year 2006 is missing from my dataset; but I want to dislay it as 0 on x axis. I think that should be possible by converting `df$year` to `factor` and setting the factor levels, following an example here: [R - how to make barplot plot zeros for missing values over the data range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148088/r-how-to-make-barplot-plot-zeros-for-missing-values-over-the-data-range) but I can't make it work.

```
df<-data.frame(year = c(2005,2007,2008, 2009),
               area = c(10,20,30,15))

barplot(df$area)
```

[image]

My not working attempt:

```
barplot(df$area, 
        names.arg = factor(df$year, 
                           levels = 2005:2009))
```

Comment: Cool, thank you ! :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `merge` with a full dataset, replace the `NA` elements to 0 and then do the `barplot`

```
df1 <- merge(data.frame(year = min(df$year):max(df$year)), df, all.x=TRUE)
df1$area[is.na(df1$area)] <- 0
barplot(setNames(df1$area, df1$year))
```

-output

[image]

---

This can also be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   complete(year = min(year):max(year), fill = list(area = 0)) %>% 
   ggplot(., aes(year, area)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
   theme_bw()
```

-output

[image]